# New with WSO2-DAS

Tags: wso2-das

WSO2 installed on Linux with Oracle-RAC. Followed all steps (I think!)
When starting it for the first time, i don't got any error:

TID: [-1234] [] [2017-04-25 15:28:17,964]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.analytics.spark.core.internal.SparkAnalyticsExecutor} -  Started Spark CLIENT in the cluster pointing to MASTER local with the application name : CarbonAnalytics and UI port : 4040 {org.wso2.carbon.analytics.spark.core.internal.SparkAnalyticsExecutor}
TID: [-1234] [] [2017-04-25 15:28:17,987]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.ml.core.internal.MLCoreDS} -  H2O Server will start in local mode. {org.wso2.carbon.ml.core.internal.MLCoreDS}
TID: [-1234] [] [2017-04-25 15:28:18,655]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.ml.core.impl.H2OServer} -  H2o Server has started. {org.wso2.carbon.ml.core.impl.H2OServer}
TID: [-1234] [] [2017-04-25 15:28:18,659]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.ml.core.internal.MLCoreDS} -  Machine Learner Wizard URL : https://172.17.9.67:9443/ml {org.wso2.carbon.ml.core.internal.MLCoreDS}
TID: [-1234] [] [2017-04-25 15:28:18,660]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.ml.core.internal.MLCoreDS} -  ML core bundle activated 
TID: [-1234] [] [2017-04-25 15:28:19,229]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.ntask.core.impl.AbstractQuartzTaskManager} -  Task scheduled: [-1234][ANALYTICS_SPARK_EVENTING][STORE_EVENT_ROUTER_TASK] {org.wso2.carbon.ntask.core.impl.AbstractQuartzTaskManager}
TID: [-1234] [] [2017-04-25 15:28:19,315]  INFO successfully. {org.wso2.carbon.ml.core.internal.MLCoreDS}{org.wso2.carbon.core.init.JMXServerManager} -  JMX Service URL  : service:jmx:rmi://localhost:11111/jndi/rmi://localhost:9999/jmxrmi {org.wso2.carbon.core.init.JMXServerManager}
TID: [-1234] [] [2017-04-25 15:28:19,358]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.StartupFinalizerServiceComponent} -  Server           :  WSO2 Data Analytics Server-3.1.0 {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.StartupFinalizerServiceComponent}
TID: [-1234] [] [2017-04-25 15:28:19,360]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.StartupFinalizerServiceComponent} -  WSO2 Carbon started in 40 sec {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.StartupFinalizerServiceComponent}
TID: [-1234] [] [2017-04-25 15:28:19,983]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.ui.internal.CarbonUIServiceComponent} -  Mgt Console URL  : https://172.17.9.67:9443/carbon/ {org.wso2.carbon.ui.internal.CarbonUIServiceComponent}
TID: [-1] [] [2017-04-25 15:28:45,332]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.event.processor.manager.core.internal.CarbonEventManagementService} -  Starting polling event receivers {org.wso2.carbon.event.processor.manager.core.internal.CarbonEventManagementService}

But I'm not able to run console, nothing showed when loading http url :-(

Also trying 172.17.9.67:9763/carbon/ after deleting comment on AllowHttp label

Comment: Can you specify the WSO2 DAS version ?

Comment: Sure! wso2das-3.1.0